# Drawing multiples technical graphs

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics

I wonder if it possible to draw multiples same graphs using parameter values.
The graphs shown in attached pic.

Thanks

[image]

Comment: The answer is almost certainly yes. But your question as phrased is too broad. Concerning the specific graphs shown, it would be probably quicker (for me anyway) to draw them by hand using IPE than trying to figure out appropriate coordinates for tikz.

Comment: There should be some examples on this site or on the Internet in general a lot of examples similar to these drawings which you could consult in order to get a basic idea of how to draw such diagrams using Ti*k*Z. On this site, it is best to provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that shows what you tried so far, because it is much simpler to help you with where you got stuck

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the partial working code (to You to finish the work):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        % first picture
        \draw[line width=1,-latex] (0,0)--(6,0);
        \draw[line width=1,-latex] (0,0)--(0,4) node[left] () {\bfseries $f$(Hz)};
        \draw[line width=3pt] (0,3.5)--(5,1);
        \draw[dashed] (0,3) node[left] () {$f_0$}--(14,3)
                (1,3)--(1,0) node[below] () {$P_1$}
                (3,2)--(3,0) node[below] () {$P'_1$}
                (0,2) node[left] () {$f'_1$}--(14,2);
        \draw[line width=1,-latex] (5.5,3.5)--(5.5,3);
        \draw[line width=1,-latex] (5.5,1.5)--(5.5,2);
        \draw[line width=1pt,latex-latex] (1,.5)--(3,.5) node[midway,above] () {$\Delta P_1$};
        \node at (5.5,2.5) {$\Delta\ f$};
        \node at (2.5,3.8) {$f-f_0=k_{P_1}(P'_1-P_1)$};
        % second picture
        \draw[line width=1,-latex] (8,0)--(14,0);
        \draw[line width=1,-latex] (8,0)--(8,4) node[left] () {\bfseries $f$(Hz)};
        \draw[line width=3pt] (8,3.5)--(13,1.5);
        \draw[dashed] (0,3)--(9,3)
        (9,3)--(9,0) node[below] () {$P_2$}
        (11.8,2)--(11.8,0) node[below] () {$P'_2$}
        (8,2)--(14,2);
        \draw[line width=1pt,latex-latex] (9,.5)--(11.8,.5) node[midway,above] () {$\Delta P_2$};
        \node at (10.5,3.8) {$f-f_0=k_{P_2}(P'_2-P_2)$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
    \vspace{1.5 cm}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        % you put here (copy and paste with some corrections the third and the forth picture)
    \end{tikzpicture}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Hi Raffaele, Thank you for your detailed answer, Great.

Comment: @Tommy_TSA If You agree with my answer, You can accept this. For me was a lot of work.